# Prevent each img from being effected in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When a user slides the jQuery Slider over, it effects each image. How do I only get the images pertaining to that slider to change?

I've tried:
`$(this).closest('img.down')` and `$(this).siblings('img.down')`

```
$("#slider").slider({
  value:50,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 50,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $('img.up, img.down').css('opacity','.4');
    if (ui.value >= 51) {
      $('img.up').css('opacity','.8');
    }
    if (ui.value <= 49) {
      $('img.down').css('opacity','.8');
    }
  }
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/psybJ/5/)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make a change to your markup, ***you cannot have three items in a page with the same id***. You can make it

```
class="slider"
```

Move the initialization of the CSS outside of the function then traverse the markup to get the correct image:

```
$('img.up, img.down').css('opacity','.4');
$(".slider").slider({
  value:50,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 50,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
  if (ui.value == 50) {
      $(this).parent().find('img.up, img.down').css('opacity','.4');
  }
  if (ui.value >= 51) {
      $(this).parent().find('img.up').css('opacity','.8');
  }
  if (ui.value <= 49) {
      $(this).parent().find('img.down').css('opacity','.8');
  }
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/psybJ/9/

Answer (score 0):

`siblings` works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/psybJ/8/

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 50,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).siblings('img.up, img.down').css('opacity', '.4');
        if(ui.value >= 51) {
            $(this).siblings('img.up').css('opacity', '.8');
        }
        if(ui.value <= 49) {
            $(this).siblings('img.down').css('opacity', '.8');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Siblings will work, but only for the first slider in your fiddle becuae he has the sliders setup with id's, not classes. There are three id's with the same name, so only the first slider works.

Answer (score 0):

You really should replace "id" with "class" for your sliders. if you do that then this code will work fine:

```
$(".slider").slider({
  value:50,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 50,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    if (ui.value >= 51) {
      $('img.up',parent).css('opacity','.8');
      $('img.down',parent).css('opacity','.4');
    }
    else if (ui.value <= 49) {
      $('img.down',parent).css('opacity','.8');
      $('img.up',parent).css('opacity','.4');
    }
  }
});
```